# (14) cannot open file at line 30192 of [00bb9c9ce4]

Tags: android, database, eclipse, sqlite

Error when running my application.

Test error in Android 4.4 and 5.1

### logcat

> 03-20 18:57:37.539: E/SQLiteLog(11840): (14) cannot open file at line 30192 of [00bb9c9ce4]
>   03-20 18:57:37.539: E/SQLiteLog(11840): (14) os_unix.c:30192: (2) open(//data//data//com.parandsoft.nitrospeed//databases//mem_boost.db) - 
>   03-20 18:57:37.559: E/SQLiteDatabase(11840): Failed to open database '//data//data//com.parandsoft.nitrospeed//databases//mem_boost.db'.
>   03-20 18:57:37.559: E/SQLiteDatabase(11840): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
>   03-20 18:57:37.559: E/SQLiteDatabase(11840):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
>   03-20 18:57:37.559: E/SQLiteDatabase(11840):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:209)
>   03-20 18:57:37.559: E/SQLiteDatabase(11840):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
>   03-20 18:57:37.559: E/SQLiteDatabase(11840):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
>   03-20 18:57:37.559: E/SQLiteDatabase(11840):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
>   03-20 18:57:37.559: E/SQLiteDatabase(11840):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
>   03-20 18:57:37.559: E/SQLiteDatabase(11840):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:804)
>   03-20 18:57:37.559: E/SQLiteDatabase(11840):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:789)
>   03-20 18:57:37.559: E/SQLiteDatabase(11840):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
>   03-20 18:57:37.559: E/SQLiteDatabase(11840):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:669)
>   03-20 18:57:37.559: E/SQLiteDatabase(11840):    at com.parandsoft.nitrospeed.db.ExternalDbOpenHelper.checkDataBase(ExternalDbOpenHelper.java:67)
>   03-20 18:57:37.559: E/SQLiteDatabase(11840):    at com.parandsoft.nitrospeed.db.ExternalDbOpenHelper.createDataBase(ExternalDbOpenHelper.java:49)
>   03-20 18:57:37.559: E/SQLiteDatabase(11840):    at com.parandsoft.nitrospeed.db.ExternalDbOpenHelper.openDataBase(ExternalDbOpenHelper.java:106)
>   03-20 18:57:37.559: E/SQLiteDatabase(11840):    at com.parandsoft.nitrospeed.db.ExternalDbOpenHelper.(ExternalDbOpenHelper.java:44)
>   03-20 18:57:37.559: E/SQLiteDatabase(11840):    at com.parandsoft.nitrospeed.ActionBarBaseActivity.onCreate(ActionBarBaseActivity.java:60)
>   03-20 18:57:37.559: E/SQLiteDatabase(11840):    at com.parandsoft.nitrospeed.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:59)
>   03-20 18:57:37.559: E/SQLiteDatabase(11840):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
>   03-20 18:57:37.559: E/SQLiteDatabase(11840):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>   03-20 18:57:37.559: E/SQLiteDatabase(11840):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)
>   03-20 18:57:37.559: E/SQLiteDatabase(11840):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2271)
>   03-20 18:57:37.559: E/SQLiteDatabase(11840):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
>   03-20 18:57:37.559: E/SQLiteDatabase(11840):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
>   03-20 18:57:37.559: E/SQLiteDatabase(11840):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>   03-20 18:57:37.559: E/SQLiteDatabase(11840):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>   03-20 18:57:37.559: E/SQLiteDatabase(11840):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5179)
>   03-20 18:57:37.559: E/SQLiteDatabase(11840):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   03-20 18:57:37.559: E/SQLiteDatabase(11840):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>   03-20 18:57:37.559: E/SQLiteDatabase(11840):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:732)
>   03-20 18:57:37.559: E/SQLiteDatabase(11840):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
>   03-20 18:57:37.559: E/SQLiteDatabase(11840):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>       03-20 18:58:07.099: E/audio_a2dp_hw(431): adev_set_parameters: ERROR: set param   called even when stream out is null

Here is my code:

```
public class ExternalDbOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

  // Path to the device folder with databases
  public static String DB_PATH;

  // Database file name
  public static String DB_NAME;
  public SQLiteDatabase database;
  public final Context context;

  public SQLiteDatabase getDb() {
    return database;
  }

  public ExternalDbOpenHelper(Context context, String databaseName,
                              int databaseVersion) {
    super(context, databaseName, null, databaseVersion);
    this.context = context;
    // Write a full path to the databases of your application
    String packageName = context.getPackageName();
    DB_PATH = String.format("//data//data//%s//databases//", packageName);
    DB_NAME = databaseName;
    openDataBase();
  }

  // This piece of code will create a database if it's not yet created
  public void createDataBase() {
    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
    if (!dbExist) {

      this.getReadableDatabase();
      try {
        copyDataBase();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        //Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "Copying error");
        throw new Error("Error copying database!");
      }
    }
  }

  // Performing a database existence check
  private boolean checkDataBase() {
    SQLiteDatabase checkDb = null;
    try {
      String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
      checkDb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null,
          SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      //Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "Error while checking db");
    }
    // Android doesn?t like resource leaks, everything should
    // be closed
    if (checkDb != null) {
      checkDb.close();
    }
    return checkDb != null;
  }

  // Method for copying the database
  private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
    // Open a stream for reading from our ready-made database
    // The stream source is located in the assets
    InputStream externalDbStream = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    // Path to the created empty database on your Android device
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    // Now create a stream for writing the database byte by byte
    OutputStream localDbStream = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    // Copying the database
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = externalDbStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
      localDbStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    // Don?t forget to close the streams
    localDbStream.close();
    externalDbStream.close();
  }

  public SQLiteDatabase openDataBase() throws SQLException {
    String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    if (database == null) {
      createDataBase();
    }
    database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null,
        SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    return database;
  }

  @Override
  public synchronized void close() {
    if (database != null) {
      database.close();
    }
    super.close();
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
  }

  @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
  }

  public void insertAutoKillApps(final ArrayList<AppInfo> listAutoKillApps) {
    for (int i = 0; i < listAutoKillApps.size(); i++) {
      if (listAutoKillApps.get(i).isChecked()) {
        AppInfo info = listAutoKillApps.get(i);
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(Const.TblAutoKillColumn.APP_NAME, info.getAppName());
        values.put(Const.TblAutoKillColumn.PACKAGE_NAME,
            info.getPkgName());
        values.put(Const.TblAutoKillColumn.PROCESS_ID,
            info.getProcessId());
        int id = (int) database.insert(Const.TABLE_AUTO_KILL, null,
            values);

      }
    }
  }

  public int insertAutoKillApp(AppInfo info) {

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Const.TblAutoKillColumn.APP_NAME, info.getAppName());
    values.put(Const.TblAutoKillColumn.PACKAGE_NAME, info.getPkgName());
    int id = (int) database.insert(Const.TABLE_AUTO_KILL, null, values);
    return id;

  }

  public int insertAllAutoKillApp(ArrayList<AppInfo> list) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
      AppInfo info = list.get(i);
      ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
      values.put(Const.TblAutoKillColumn.APP_NAME, info.getAppName());
      values.put(Const.TblAutoKillColumn.PACKAGE_NAME, info.getPkgName());
      int id = (int) database.insert(Const.TABLE_AUTO_KILL, null, values);
      if (id != -1) {
        count += 1;
      }
    }
    System.out.println("Total app kill inserted " + count);
    return count;

  }

  public boolean deleteAutoKillApp(AppInfo info) {

    int row = database.delete(Const.TABLE_AUTO_KILL,
        Const.TblAutoKillColumn.PACKAGE_NAME + " = ?",
        new String[]{info.getPkgName()});

    if (row != 0) {
      return true;
    }

    return false;

  }

  public int deleteAllAutoKillApp(ArrayList<AppInfo> list) {

    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
      AppInfo info = list.get(i);
      int row = database.delete(Const.TABLE_AUTO_KILL,
          Const.TblAutoKillColumn.PACKAGE_NAME + " = ?",
          new String[]{info.getPkgName()});
      if (row != 0) {
        count += 1;
      }
    }
    System.out.println("Total app kill deleted " + count);
    return count;
  }

  public ArrayList<AppInfo> getAutoKillApps() {
    ArrayList<AppInfo> appList = new ArrayList<AppInfo>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + Const.TABLE_AUTO_KILL;
    try {

      Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
      if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
          do {

            AppInfo info = new AppInfo();
            info.setAppName(cursor.getString(0));
            info.setPkgName(cursor.getString(1));
            appList.add(info);
          } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
      }

      return appList;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      return appList;
    }
  }

  public int insertUsedAppInfo(UsedAppInfo uAppInfo, boolean isUpdate) {
    int id = 0;
    if (isUpdate) {
      ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
      values.put(Const.TblAppUsedColumn.OPEN_COUNTER,
          uAppInfo.getCounter());
      values.put(Const.TblAppUsedColumn.OPEN_TIME, uAppInfo.getTime());
      String[] args = new String[]{uAppInfo.getPackage_name()};
      id = (int) database.update(Const.TABLE_APP_USED_DETAIL, values,
          Const.TblAppUsedColumn.PACKAGE_NAME + "=?", args);
    } else {
      ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
      values.put(Const.TblAppUsedColumn.PACKAGE_NAME,
          uAppInfo.getPackage_name());
      values.put(Const.TblAppUsedColumn.OPEN_COUNTER,
          uAppInfo.getCounter());
      values.put(Const.TblAppUsedColumn.OPEN_TIME, uAppInfo.getTime());
      id = (int) database.insert(Const.TABLE_APP_USED_DETAIL, null,
          values);
    }
    return id;
  }

  public UsedAppInfo gettUsedAppInfo(String packageName) {
    UsedAppInfo uAppInfo = null;
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + Const.TABLE_APP_USED_DETAIL
        + " WHERE " + Const.TblAppUsedColumn.PACKAGE_NAME + " = "
        + "\"" + packageName + "\"";

    try {

      Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
      if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
          uAppInfo = new UsedAppInfo();
          uAppInfo.setPackage_name(cursor.getString(0));
          uAppInfo.setCounter(cursor.getInt(1));
          uAppInfo.setTime(cursor.getString(2));
        }
        cursor.close();
      }

      return uAppInfo;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      //Log.d("Error in getting app info from db", e.getMessage());
      return null;
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: For a prepopulated database, consider using [sqlite-asset-helper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) and not a broken version of code that does not work.

Comment: Improved English and code formatting